# linux / unix における、ユーザー固有のアプリケーション設定の、標準的な置き場は?

Tags: linux, unix

たとえば、 cli ツールを自前で作っていたとします。その設定ファイルなどを、ユーザーごとに設定したくなります。

## 質問

ユーザー固有の設定を保存する場所について、標準的なパスの規約はありますか?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

現在は、[XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/) に従って、環境変数 `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` が指定するディレクトリ（環境変数が設定されていない場合は `$HOME/.config`）の下に設定ファイルを置くのが標準的な慣習となっています。

Answer (score 3):

伝統的にはマルチユーザーでの利用が前提なので、まずは各ユーザーのホームディレクトリ以下に置けばよくて、単一の設定ファイルで済むなら `.APPNAMErc` のようにいわゆるドットファイルで名前の末尾に `rc` を付けて設定ファイルと分かるようにしているケースが多いと思います。

設定ファイルが複数になるようであれば、ホームディレクトリ直下に `.APPNAME/` の形式でディレクトリを作成しているケースもあります。